# Convert 1-5V to 4-20mA using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage, analog

I am trying to convert 1-5V to 0-20mA which is then used to drive VFD.

[image]Actually, I want 1-5V Variable output from Arduino. I am using PWM but its output 0V or 5V depending upon the duty cycle.

Is their any method to obtain any voltage between 1-5V using Arduino or any other module/controller?

Comment: Also asked on EE yesterday: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501845/4-20ma-output-from-arduino-nano

Comment: By tuning R4 and C1 and using an appropriate PWM frequency and duty cycle, you already have a (simple and slow) D/A converter that can generate voltages between 0 and 5V, but this might not fit your needs. How fast does it need to be? There are many DACs available to be interfaced with Arduinos.

Comment: @VE7JRO, to be fair, that question was about a 4-20mA output. Now they need to generate a 1-5V input for the same circuit and already added an RC filter to try to accomplish that.

Comment: @StarCat - The first sentence in the OP's question on EE is "To convert 1-5V to 0-20mA:". Their first sentence here on Ard.SE is very similar. The OP's question on EE has not received any answers, so maybe someone here has the answer. The 741 OP Amp part of the question is better suited for EE because it's off topic for our network, and the OP may want to read this first before choosing that OP Amp: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp

Comment: Make C1 ten times bigger.

Comment: just use a low pass filter to convert pwm to analog voltage. if you need responsiveness, a 2-stage filter will respond quicker at the same ripple level than a single RC filter. You will likely need an op-amp unity gain amp (aka buffer) after the filter to allow the needed current (RC filters will severely restrict current). To convert the 0-5v to 0-20ma, you can just drive a 250 ohm resistor. If you want 4-20ma, use the map() function to scale.

Comment: One cannot use an Arduino to convert 1..5V to 4..20mA.